# How do I access the url path params from GoRouter when using a MultiBlocProvider?

Tags: flutter, bloc, gorouter

Currently we're building an app to learn Flutter and Bloc pattern at my company. We use a `MultiRepositoryProvider` as the main widget and GoRouter for routing. My route looks like this:

```
GoRoute(
    path: '/game/:id',
    builder: (context, state) => GameDetailScreen(),
),
```

In the `MultiRepositoryProvider` the child is a `MultiBlocProvider` and the provider for this screen is:

```
BlocProvider(
    create: (BuildContext context) {
        return GameDetailBloc(context.read<FirestoreRepo>());
    },
),
```

The BlocProvider's `create` function returns the `BuildContext` but it's not clear to me how I get the GoRoute state to pass the url param `id` to the `GameDetailBloc`.

We managed to get this to work by setting the game's `id` in GoRoute's build function when creating the  `GameDetailScreen`. Then we removed that `BlocProvider` in the `MultiBlocProvider` and then accessed the bloc from the `BuildContext` when building the widget but it doesn't seem correct and we're trying to find the "correct solution" to this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand the whole question. But as much I understand you want to pass "id" param in GameDetailBloc and want to know how to access the same. You can do that using GoRoute's builder state. somewhat like this `final id= state.params['id']!;`. I hope this is what you asked.

Comment: Could you be very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `go_router` has it's `params` in its state.

*Hence pass the `state` to the page*

---

#### Router

```
 GoRoute(
    name: "test",
    path: "/test/:id",
    builder: (context, state) {
      return SampleWidget(
        goRouterState: state,   Pass state here
      );
    },
  ),
```

#### Usage

```
context.goNamed("test", params: {"id": "123"}),
```

#### Accesing in the page

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  GoRouterState? goRouterState;
  SampleWidget({super.key, this.goRouterState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(goRouterState?.params.toString());  access anywhere like so

    return const Scaffold(
      body: ...
    );
  }
}
```

*I couln't completely understand the question. I have attempted to answer based on my interpretation. Let me know the specifics if you have any other requrirements.*

Comment: @krisnaa, i have a question, if we pass data then it can be pass as state, but if i need url base filter, like date filter, usually same url show all data and nothing to show url until user put new filter with date, so we can not pass null or empty string in url 

Example: 

http://myweb.com/list => show all data
http://myweb.com/list/from_date/to_date => show filtered data

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.base.toString().replaceAll(Uri.base.origin, '')
```